# How do i make on MenuStrip a switch button to change colors when clicking on a menu?

Tags: c#

I have this menu click event for example:

```
private void testToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (testToolStripMenuItem.Checked == true)
            {
                testToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                testToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }
```

I want to do that when the user click once on the menu the menu text will be in Red and once he clicked on it again it will back in Black.

Another thing/problem: How can i avoid/disable that when the user move the mouse over the menu so the menu is painted in blue around it how can i make that when the user move the mouse over the menu it will be regular and wil not painted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change the forecolor of item in `checkedChange` event .

```
private void testToolStripMenuItem_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ( testToolStripMenuItem.Checked == true)
        testToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    else
        testToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = Color.Black;
}
```

Comment: Hamed working great i used a flag to do it called it buttonSiwtch . But your solution is also working great !

Comment: Now i need or i want to solve the second problem when moving the mouse over the menu its painting the menu around in blue or is it pale blue...

Comment: @daniellip I didn't find any way to disable hilights on menuItem.

Comment: @DanielLip As far as your second problem it can be done, you will need to create a Custom ToolStripMenuItem and handle the painting in the OnPaint event. This is called an OwnerDrawn control. There is an example of a Custom Control on this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.aspx#Y6827) page.